# Decrypt (homomorphically and symmetrically) encrypted data using (homomorphically) encrypted key?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

Is it possible to do the following?

1. Generate symmetric key $K$
2. Encrypt data $D$ with the symmetric key : $E_k{(D)}$
3. Encrypt the symmetric key and the encrypted data using homomorphic encryption scheme (e.g. Paillier) with FHE key : $E_{paillier}(E_k{(D))}$ and $E_{paillier}(K)$
4. Send both $E_{paillier}(E_k{(D))}$ and $E_{paillier}(K)$ to the other third party
5. The third party (symmetric) decrypt using it and outputs $E_{paillier}(D)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible as long as the homomorphic cipher supports all operations necessary to implement the symmetric encryption algorithm. So for a partially homomorphic cipher like Paillier, this will not be possible. With a fully-homomorphic cipher (or somewhat homomorphic cipher configured with sufficient multiplicative depth), this is very feasible, even for standard symmetric algorithms like AES.

For example see [Homomorphic Evaluation of the AES Circuit](https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/099.pdf). AES has become a sort of defacto standard benchmark for fully homomorphic ciphers.

See also [Ciphers for MPC and FHE](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/687.pdf), where the researchers look at designing secure symmetric ciphers that are specifically optimized towards homomorphic evaluation.